# Selenium - Three different welcome screens

Tags: java, selenium, homescreen

I tried to write automatic tests for mobile application: "Vinted". I can't make the LoginScreen, because this application has 3 different home screens which loads randomly with different ID for a login button.

I would like you to ask to write a code which: Try to click A. If there is no A it tries to click B. If there is no B then tries to click C.

I tried with:

```
try {
btn_register1.click();
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        btn_register2.click();
        btn_register3.click();
        }
```

btn_register 1 and 2 works. But then it comes to a 3 test fails. I want to add that I am very much a beginner with Selenium and JAVA.

Comment: In this case maybe consider locating login button by something else than _id_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What wil happen then `btn_register2.click();` throw exception?

You can add one more try-catch block inside catch part, but it's better to do check before you'are clicking on element.

```
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By by);
    if (elements.size() > 0)
        elements.get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with try catch block, you can do like this:

```
 try {
        btn_register1.click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        try {
            btn_register2.click();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException f) {
            btn_register3.click();
        }
    }
```